# Android findViewById returns null ...

Tags: android, android-layout

i am try to find my drawer layout but findViewById returns null and i don't know why... here is my code.

```
// NavigationBaseActivity        
@Override
    public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {
        LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(layoutResID, (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.content), true);

        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        if (drawerLayout != null) {
            drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.string.navigation_open, R.string.navigation_close);
            drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
        }

        setupToolbar();
    }


public class OverviewActivity extends NavigationBaseActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_overview);
    }
}
```

My drawerLayout is always null... this is my xml layout file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <include layout="@layout/toolbar"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/navigation"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Can anybody help me.. i can find the others views but the drawer layout is stubborn... thanks

Comment: why are you overriding `setContentView()`? you are not calling `super.setContentView()` as far as I can see...

Comment: Yes do your stuff in onCreate. I believe that in setContentView there is no view yet where findViewById can find something. Or do first call super.setContentView() to bring up your layout first.